# Trouble Creating REST project using start.spring.io

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

[image][image]Having trouble getting with start.spring.io generated project to work in Eclipse.
I'm so used to right-clicking on the pom.xml file and seeing 'update maven', but I don't see that.

The imports for the spring framework are all red.
See the attached screen shots, please.

Do I need to move to a later version of eclipse?
I do have the STS platform installed but I do not want an embedded tomcat, I'd like to release my war to another running instance of tomcat elsewhere.

Using start.spring.io I selected Spring Web as a dependency.

**Specs:**

```
Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)
Build id: 20180619-1200
Java : 1.8
```

Comment: Which screenshots are you talking about?

Comment: I just added the pics, I forgot previously

Comment: Yes, you should move to a later version than one that's approaching 3 years old, but more likely you were supposed to make "demo" the project folder itself rather than having it as a folder inside of another project. `pom.xml` files go in the root of the project.

Comment: I upgraded to a later Eclipse, seems to be working now. Using STS, I was able to right-click and start the project, but the Eclipse browser states :                    "Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback."  The Project is named 'demo' and the URL I am trying is: http://localhost:8080/demo

Comment: ok, I added a index.html into the static folder. I think I am finding my way. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrading helped a lot.
I can get "something" running now.